# How to differentiate between multiple config.h headers in meson.build subprojects?

Tags: c, glib, meson-build, harfbuzz, pixman

I am currently developing a library in C, using meson.build. The library contains several dependencies and I'm using wrap-files and fallback-arguments in the meson-build to integrate these dependencies as subprojects.

I'm now aiming to build the entire project, including its dependencies, in one build-step in order to e.g. consistently build and link everything with `-fsanitize=address` (another use-case may be differing compiler-/linker-flags). In order to do so, I use the `-Dwrap_mode=forcefallback` flag for meson.

However, one of the dependencies is `harfbuzz` (https://github.com/harfbuzz/harfbuzz). I figured out that it is impossible to build `harfbuzz` with the given flag. This is mainly caused by multiple `config.h`-files. Specifically I overall get this list of config-files in my build-directory after the configuration step:

```
$ find . -name config.h
./config.h
./subprojects/pixman/pixman/config.h
./subprojects/glib-2.74.1/config.h
./subprojects/gperf/config.h
./subprojects/pcre2-10.40/config.h
./subprojects/cairo/config.h
```

The pixman-library itself will check the include-order and as a different `config.h`-file is chosen in contrast to the pixman-specific one, it will complain with an `#error`-directive. It is therefore currently impossible to build `harfbuzz` with the `-Dwrap_mode=forcefallback`-flag.

Libpixman itself does not use meson-build-subprojects, despite offering meson-build files. Otherwise the problem might have been visible therein already (it contains the `glib-2` dependency by itself already).

My question is therefore related to meson-build best practices: How could I ensure in such a scenario that every subproject will always choose its own `config.h`? Or is it better to create a `config.h` in the upstream project that - depending on the chosen subproject structure - is always able to replace every `config.h` of every subproject?

Comment: This sounds like a harfbuzz bug - maybe their meson.build file is adding the top project dir to the include paths, instead of the top subproject dir.

Comment: I figured out that it could be fixed by changing the order of dependencies in the meson-file of pixman. After using the pixman-dependency as first element, the correct include path was chosen by the compiler. However, I'm not sure how stable or reliable this approach is, as this property is not mentioned in the mesonbuild documentation.
Still, I filed an [issue in pixman](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pixman/pixman/-/issues/70) about this and some other issues that will also prevent a usage as subproject